# Issue exporting Numeric data to Flat file , SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have numeric data with have value `0.546, 0.456` in the database.  When I try to export these values to flat file using flat file manager the zero value is truncated and only `.546,.456` is shown in the flat file.

The value other than zero doesn't have this problem.
I tried using data conversion but of no use

Comment: Mathematically, those numbers are identical - what is the actual problem? are you unable to import these? Are you opening the output file in a text editor (not Excel)?

Comment: in the flat file (txt) the values are showing as .546 instead of 0.546

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Some interesting discussion on this topic can be found here: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52352.html - The crux of the discussion there is that decimal without a preceding zero could be missed while reading.  Last but not the least, if the requirement or the boss says it's needed, we got to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

Try Data Conversion transform - Data Type: decimal [DT-DECIMAL) : Scale 3. 
Good find, Prakash!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to first convert you numeric data to `DT_WSTR`. It has to be Derived Column transformation, not Data Conversion, because you'd get the same result. In expression you need to prepend converted number with 0. Don't know about negative numbers, but maybe they will have correct format (you need to test it).

```
floor(decimal_column)==0 ? "0" + (DT_WSTR,10)decimal_column : (DT_WSTR,10)decimal_column
```

I know that's not what you expected, but I had the same problem the other day and was unable to finde better solution :).