# Exporting numeric to flat files

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm creating a file export and a number of these fields are set up as numeric(18,4) in both the source table and flat file column. When the file is generated, any numbers which are < 1 are shown as .#, i.e. .52, instead of 0.52.

What needs to be done to fix this? The only way I can think of which neither are ideal methods are :
1. Output them as strings
2. Use a derived columns on all the numeric fields.

Comment: For the user who neg voted my question, it would be appreciative if you could explain why?

Comment: Does this actually cause problems when you come to import the data from the flat file?  Surely whatever you are importing to can be told they are numeric values and will handle them as <1 appropriately?

Comment: The number is stored correctly. It's when we export it to a file, the 0 get's cut off. It's a problem since we are exporting to an external system, which we have no control over.

Comment: It seems like I have to go with the solution I wanted to avoid as per this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440806/issue-exporting-numeric-data-to-flat-file-ssis

Comment: Why is it "less than ideal" to output them as strings?  If you're exporting them to a flat file, outputting strings sounds pretty ideal to me.  It's absolutely what I would do.

Comment: Less idea in that you need to convert all your numerical columns to varchars before exporting. Surely there should be an option to allow you to export numericals and specify the format needed.